# Do text and binary mode regex search always return the same result?

Tags: python

Python's [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) says:

> Both patterns and strings to be searched can be Unicode strings (str) as well as 8-bit strings (bytes).

But I was wondering whether searching with `str` and `bytes` would always give the same result. I mean, whether this function returns true, for all valid `pattern` and `string`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
def test(pattern, string):
    m = re.search(pattern, string)
    mb = re.search(pattern.encode(), string.encode())
    if m is None and mb is None: return True
    i, j = m.span(0)
    ib, jb = mb.span(0)
    return string[i:j].encode() == string.encode()[ib:jb]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer: no

example: `test('[–]', '–')`

note that's an "en-dash" and not a hyphen — any non-ASCII character should have the same behaviour

Comment: Did that throw an exception? The initial code does not consider the case of no match, for brevity. Now it is updated.

Comment: nope, not with the original code nor the updated…  I'm using Python 3.7 if that matters

Comment: Saw your updates. Doesn't seem to be a python version problem. More like a valid counter example...

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is in classes.

For example, U+00FF is `"ÿ"`, but is not an ASCII character. So `\w` (Match "word character", or letters)

```
re.search(r'\w', '\xFF')  # match
re.search(rb'\w', b'\xFF')  # no match
re.search(rb'\w', '\xFF'.encode())  # still no match
```

(And other unicode letters would work too)

If you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, you can see the three classes this applies to:

> `\d`
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> > Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes `[0-9]`, and also many other digit characters. If the `ASCII` flag is used only `[0-9]` is matched.
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
>
> > Matches characters considered whitespace in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.

> `\s`
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> > Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages). If the `ASCII` flag is used, only `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` is matched.
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
>
> > Matches characters considered whitespace in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.

> `\w`
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> > Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the `ASCII` flag is used, only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched.
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
>
> > Matches characters considered alphanumeric in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If the `LOCALE` flag is used, matches characters considered alphanumeric in the current locale and the underscore.

So if you set the [`ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) flag, they should be mostly the same.

For your exact function, an example would be: `test(r'\w|.', '\xFF')`